# Enable user access to a specific folder within Marketing Cloud FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ftp, sftp

We would like to a create a new MC FTP User who will have permissions (read and write) only for a specific folder within our MC FTP. Is this can be achieved? We haven't found anything related in the documentation - perhaps some kind of a workaround is needed?

Many Thanks,

Barak

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have folder specific access in Enhanced FTP. All the users which are created in a specific Business Unit, all share access to same folder structure.

If having multiple users with different access rights on specific folders, the only option is an external SFTP where you can work with more specific permissions.